# Keycloak as Docker image stuck in admin console Openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, keycloak

I create a Keycloak docker image and deploy it in Openshift as image container. It stucks in admin UI keep facing 403 forbidden from login-status-iframe endpoint.

This is my keycloak.conf:

```
http-enabled=true
hostname-strict=false
hostname-strict-https=false
proxy=edge
hostname-url=https://mytest.com
hostname-admin-url=https://mytest.com

https-certificate-file=/opt/key/bin/server.crt
https-certificate-key-file=/opt/key/bin/server.key
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using proxy=edge ? And with which url are you trying to access the admin UI?